# app to run only one instance in Windows and show form when main form is hide

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a winform app via one form and need app to run only one instance in Windows
i cant show form when this **hide**

**i need a clear code for show my hidden form**

in my form

```
this.Hide();
```

program.cs  for run only one instance in Windows and focused on app
and **my question is how show main form when is hide() ???**

```
        static void Main()
        {
         System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
         System.Diagnostics.Process me = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
         foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in myProcesses)
         {
            if (p.ProcessName == me.ProcessName)
               if (p.Id != me.Id)
               {   
                  SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
                  SwitchToThisWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, true);
                  return;
               }
         }
       // continue normally
       }


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
```

**update:**  above code is fine for **Foreground Window** and **minimize window**... its OK. **My problem is how to show hidden form???**

sorry for my English

Comment: `this.Show()` ?..

Comment: It is a built-in feature.  Google "windows forms single instance" to learn how to use it.

Comment: no no. i need to show form on other proccess

Comment: The other process instance doesn't exist if your app is _**single instance**_. You need to make it a multi instance process if you want to be able to open another one.

Comment: tnq. i try single instance

Comment: No, I said _**it would NOT**_ work if your app is single instance...

Comment: Find your process by its name and then use your code above. What's the issue?

Comment: i found solution. if u need this can use :) its perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution. any code in NewInstanceHandler() run on old proccess :) i checked it via proccess ID. i think its best soultion.

for add **Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices** right click on reference and checked **Microsoft.VisualBasic**.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

static Form1 MainForm;
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    MainForm = new Form1();
    SingleInstanceApplication.Run(MainForm,  NewInstanceHandler);
}

public static void NewInstanceHandler(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
{   
    // anything u need run on old instance
    // MainForm.Hide();
    MainForm.Show();
    MainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    e.BringToForeground = true;
}


public class SingleInstanceApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
     private SingleInstanceApplication()
     {
        base.IsSingleInstance = true;
     }
     public static void Run(Form f, StartupNextInstanceEventHandler startupHandler)
     {
        SingleInstanceApplication app = new SingleInstanceApplication();
        app.MainForm = f;
        app.StartupNextInstance += startupHandler;
        app.Run(new string[0]);
    }        
}
```